# Recaptcha 3 and Classic ASP

Tags: recaptcha-v3

Is there an example of how to add Recaptcha 3 to a Classic asp form anywhere? I can find examples for PHP but not Classic ASP and I am not sure what the equivalent Of

$recaptcha = file_get_contents($recaptcha_url . '?secret=' . $recaptcha_secret . '&response=' . $recaptcha_response);

is in ASP - thanks

Answer (score 0):

My old classic .asp lib in my head would say something like:

```
<%
' if you have a file to read, you can use this to your local file
Set objFileToRead = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("C:\file.txt" ,1)
' but I assume you want to execute some code in a url with some parameters.
callback_response = server.exectute(recaptcha_url + "?secret=" + recaptcha_secret  + "&response=" + recaptcha_response)
%>
```